# How do I add line break in FPDF cell using multicell

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to give this particular table column a new line, so it doesn't exceed to other part of column

```
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->SetFillColor(208,208,208);
$pdf->Cell(10,8,'No.',1,0,'C',true);  
$pdf->Cell(30,8,'Barcode',1,0,'C',true);  
$pdf->Cell(80,8,'Product Name',1,0,'C',true);   //190
$pdf->Cell(25,8,'Stock',1,0,'C',true);
$pdf->Cell(45,8,'Image',1,1,'C',true);

    $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_product");
    $select->execute();
    $index = 0;

while($item = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $index++;
    $productimage = $item->pimage;
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
    $pdf->Cell(10,18,$index,1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(30,18,'8309128312',1,0,'C');
    $pdf->Cell(80,18,'Long product name that needs a line break - and more',1,1,'L');
    $pdf->Cell(25,18,'123',1,0,'C');
    if($productimage == ""){
    $pdf->Cell(45,18,'-',1,1,'C');
    } else {
    $pdf->Cell(45,18,$pdf->Image('productimages/'.$productimage, $pdf->GetX() + 15, $pdf->GetY() + 1, 11.5),1,1,'L');
    }
}
```

I have tried using `MultiCell()` for this line of code. 
`$pdf->Cell(80,18,'Long product name that needs a line break - and more',1,0,'L');` 
[Overflow text in cell table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oX4Om.jpg)

into 
`$pdf->MultiCell(80,18,'Long product name that needs a line break - and more',1,0,'L');`

I'm also aware that `MultiCell()` goes by this 
`MultiCell(float w, float h, string txt [, mixed border [, string align [, boolean fill]]])`
but I'm not sure which parameter I should fiddle around to make sure everything is in place.

[After applying MultiCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EE7Bo.png)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is confusing here is that the `float h` parameter of `MultiCell()` represents the line height, not the total height of the "cell".

Comment: thank you for point that out @KIKOSoftware but now it looks like this [link](https://i.imgur.com/tdxahc4.png) how do I rearrange the column position? I already called the Product Name column position as such `$pdf->MultiCell(80,9,'Product name .. ',1,0,'L'); `

Comment: The script [Table with MultiCells](http://www.fpdf.org/?go=script&id=3) can help.

Comment: And don't call `Image()` inside `Cell()`, it makes no sense (`Image()` returns nothing).